# Spring AOP with aspectj annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I am sorry that my question is little bit silly, but i need to understand, i am trying to write a logger based on spring aop, i know that there are several realizations, like xml based schema or aspectj annotations, in case i prefer an aspectj annotations does it means that i dont need a xml configuration file at all? I have read many tutorials and examples ones were with xml while another ones were not, now i have messed up with it, can some one give a good explanation for a newbie or mare a ref? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to using AspectJ annotations with Spring AOP then you will need a bit of XML configuration on the Spring side but can mostly manage the aspects with annotations. The XML configuration you will need is to at least:

1. Turn on AOP auto-proxy with `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`
2. Use Spring component scan to find your annotated aspects with `<context:component-scan base-package="package.of.some.aspect" />`

An example can be found [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/seemarich/archive/2007/11/annotation_base.html)

You should note there are several limitations with how AspectJ annotations apply with respect to Spring AOP, which can be found in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html)

Comment: First of all, great thanks to Niall, you really helped me to start, but i now i am stucked  with another problem. im trying to log some methods in class been annotated, i have configured a xml file and aspect class but nothing seems to be working.